# IndentationError is it tabs and spaces

Tags: python, indentation

i keep getting this error and i have no idea why IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level, i think it has something to do with spaces and tabs but im not to sure

```
import urllib2
import time
import json
import random

# Server API URLs
QUERY = "http://localhost:8080/query?id={}"

# 500 server request
N = 1


def getDataPoint(quote):
    stock = quote['stock']
    bid_price = float(quote['top_bid']['price'])
    ask_price = float(quote['top_ask']['price'])
    price = (bid_price+ask_price)/2
    return stock, bid_price, ask_price, price

def getRatio(price_ratio):
  price_a = float(price_ratio['price_a']['price'])
  price_b = float(price_ratio['price_b']['price'])

  return price_a, price_b


# Main
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # Query the price once every N seconds.
    for _ in xrange(N):
        quotes = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(QUERY.format(random.random())).read())

        """ ----------- Update to get the ratio --------------- """
        for quote in quotes:
            stock, bid_price, ask_price, price = getDataPoint(quote)
            print "Quoted %s at (bid:%s, ask:%s, price:%s)" % (stock, bid_price, ask_price, price)
    price_a , price_b = getRatio(price_ratio)
        print "Ratio %s" % (price_a, price_b)
```

Comment: Your last print is weird and getRatio function is indented with small tabs

Comment: You should also stop using camelCase with python

Answer (score -1):

Your `def getRatio(price_ratio):` seems to have to little spaces within the function

Comment: This is **incorrect** - the four-space indent is merely a community standard. The actual error was at the `price_a , price_b = getRatio(price_ratio)` code, where tabs and spaces were inappropriately mixed (in 3.x, the error message would have explicitly complained about that mixing). That said, on Stack Overflow OP is responsible for finding *where* the problem occurred and for showing a complete error message; and anyway the question should have been immediately closed as a duplicate.